# I'm getting bizzaro behavior from repeatedly and println in clojure

Tags: java, clojure

The code below is creating output that I didn't anticipate.

```
(defn my-rand []
  (let [r (rand-int 10)]
    (print "HI ")
    r)) 

(take 3 (repeatedly #(my-rand))) -> (HI HI 5 HI 5 4)
(take 4 (repeatedly #(my-rand))) -> (HI HI 7 HI 0 HI 2 9)
(take 5 (repeatedly #(my-rand))) -> (HI HI 4 HI 2 HI 4 HI 3 2)
(take 6 (repeatedly #(my-rand))) -> (HI HI 7 HI 6 HI 5 HI 6 HI 2 6)

(my-rand) -> 7 | stdout: HI
```

I found it odd that `take`...`repeatedly` produced two consecutive "HI"s. I also noticed that the final two items produced were both r. Also, interestingly, the `take`...`repeatedly` calls produced no output on stdout. Why is this?

Comment: (defn my-rand []
  (let [r (rand-int 10)]
    (print "HI " r)))

That fixes it. You're returning a number where you want to be printing a number.

Answer (score 0):

The REPL gets its name for the three phases of what it does: Read, Eval, Print Loop.

`my-rand` is returning nothing but integers.

The repl implicitly prints the result (a list of results coming from `repeatedly`). Simultaneously the `println` statements inside my-rand produce their output. The interleaving happens because unless you implement some sort of locking, output from multiple functions is unpredictable, and has no guaranteed order.

Comment: Locking isn't really relevant here: there's only one thread involved, and it will always print things in the same order. However, I think you're right that there's no guarantee that this is the case, since the REPL's print function doesn't have any particular contract to meet. As it happens, it seems to call `(next s)`, realizing two elements of `s`, in order to decide how to print the first element of `s`.

Answer (score 0):

Both `take` and `repeatedly` produce lazy sequences.  Therefore, `(take 3 (repeatedly my-rand))` will not call `my-rand` unless and as the sequence is realized (i.e., when it is traversed).  So if you never do anything with the resulting seq, you won't see anything on stdout.

As noisesmith points out, if you're in the REPL, the REPL will print the value returned by the expression you give it.  In this vase, `(take 3 (repeatedly my-rand))` will produce an unrealized lazy seq.  The REPL will then print that seq.  The print function iterates over the seq and, along with a little formatting, prints each element of the seq.  Since the seq was previously unrealized, these elements will need to be realized before they can be printed.  Now realizing an element means calling `my-rand`, which in turn calls `print`.  So the `print` calls within `my-rand` are being interleaved with the printing of each element.

Given that we have a lazy seq, I can see why it would be surprising to see two "HI"s printed in a row.  After all (assuming no elements have previously been realized), since elements are printed one at a time, shouldn't we see exactly one "HI" before each element?  As amalloy alludes to in a comment on noisesmith's answer, it turns out that in order to determine whether a lazy seq has a next element, that next element (if it exists) must be realized.  Apparently, that determination is made before printing the current element.  As a result, the first two elements are realized before the first one is printed.  Thus the two "HI"s.  However, for subsequent elements, the "current" element has already been realized in order to print the "previous" element, so only the "next" element (if there is one) needs to be realized at that point.